# Want textview to change color with click just like on a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make the user feel when clicked on a text field just like when we click on a button and and after releasing the button it goes to orange color for a very short time a blink and again turns into it's first color. When I clicks on it does work well but no color blinking appears.

Layout file

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

mainActivity Code

```
textV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.help"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try to use [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) and change text color fo interval between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`

Comment: Why do you have onClick and OnClickListener? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OnTouchListener`  or you can use a selector.

```
textV.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // change color
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // set to normal color
    }

    return true;
}
});
```

Edit:

You can use a selector also. Borders and rounded rectangle. Customize the same.

bkg.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

normal.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
  <solid android:color="#0AECBF"/>    
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF" /> 
  <padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
  </shape>
```

pressed.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ff33ffff" />
 <padding android:left="5dp"
             android:top="5dp"
             android:right="5dp"
             android:bottom="5dp"/> 
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
             android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Now set the background

```
     android:background="@drawable/bkg"
```

Comment: I would like to suggest you to try the selector as I have suggested. Your code works too

Comment: @user2041902 i have used the selector myself everywhere. i know that works too. i have suggested the same in many of my answers also.

Comment: @user2041902 posted the selector part also. check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an selector as background drawable. Create a new Android xml file with "selector" into the drawable folder:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <color android:color="@android:color/black" />
</item>
<item>
    <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
</item>
   </selector>
```

and then, in Your xml layout, set this to Your textView:

```
    android:background="@drawable/your_selector"
```

This is only a poor example, You can create shapes.xml for different backgrounds etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="#002233"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#112233"/>
    <item android:drawable="#001122"></item>
</selector>
```

Create a xml file (say text_bkgrnd) in layout folder add the above code in it.

Now in main.xml set textView's background attribute to this the created xml file

Hope this helps. Change the hash value of states as required

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#61ab69" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#009933"
                android:endColor="#00bf33"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

save it as btnclick.xml in drawable folder
and use it as

```
android:background="@drawable/btnclick
```

in that text view

it will works fine

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is setting the onTouchListener. Something like this

```
myButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        // Change your color here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

the onTouchListener should fire before the onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

property for button

```
android:background="@drawable/focus_color.xml"
```

//focus_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_focus" 
        /> <!--pressed  -->
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_titlebar" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_paint" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

//gradient_focus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#e8ebef"
        android:type="linear" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.3dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <corners android:radius="0.5dp" />

</shape>
```

//gradient_titlebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#E2EEFC"
        android:endColor="#BFCBD9"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

//gradient_paint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#94D7F2"
        android:endColor="#65A2DB"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```